# Is there a linear transformation with the given kernel and image?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have this problem :

$U=\{(x,y,z,t)\in R^4 | y+z+t=0\}$

$W = \{(x,y,z,t) \in R^4 | x+y=0$ and $z=2t\}$

Is there a linear transformation?

$T : R^4 \rightarrow  R^4$

That $\operatorname{Im} T = U$ and $\ker T = W$?

I don't really know where to start, I think it false but I don't have any establishment for this claim.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\dim im (T)+\dim \ker(T)=4$ by the dimension theorem. Since $\dim U=3$ and $\dim W=2$ this would yield $2+3=4$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 3):

$$\dim U=3\;,\;\;\dim W=2$$ and by the dimensions theorem:

$$\dim\,\text{Im}\,T +\dim\ker T=4$$

so the answer is *no* .